Noun form of Obsolescent
When a thing becomes obsolete, it is obsolescent.
The process of a thing becoming obsolete is an obsoletion.
What I'm looking for is a noun for a thing that that has become obsolete.
As a parallel, note that the thing in question could have become obsolete because it is ephemeral, in fact, it might simply have been ephemera.

Ephemera might not be a good analogy to what you are looking for here, as many things that are ephemeral would not normally be called ephemera. Or alternatively, if one does treat it as analogous, it may be taken to suggest that the word you are looking for doesn't exist (at least not in ordinary English). I set aside the problem that ephemera in English cannot be used for a single item (its Greek singular has not been assimilated into English, while its plural has).

obsoletion is a very unlikely choice. The full OED definition just says: rare. 1804– Obsolescence: obsoleteness. The relevant sub-definition for obsolescence is 1.a. The process or fact of becoming obsolete or outdated, or of falling into disuse.

"When a thing becomes obsolete, it is obsolescent."  When a thing becomes obsolete, it's... obsolete. Obsolescent refers to something that's becoming obsolete, is on the way to obsolescence..

OED defines obsolute as an adjective and noun; it's a variant of obsolete which is also an adjective and a noun.

noun A thing which is out of date or has fallen into disuse; a person who is outdated or behind the times. Now rare.

A thing which has become obsolete is an obsolute or an obsolete. Since obsolete as a noun is "rare" by OED standards and just sounds odd, obsolute as a noun might be preferred. It might be thought of as analogous to absolute, which is also an adjective and a noun.
While I can see this might be useful as a name for a database item or class ("What is X? It's an obsolute"), it's not going to be easily understood in everyday usage. Far better simply to use the adjective: "X is obsolete".

+1 for an obsolutely charming word. :)

I love obsolute (and it actually is to be used in database documentation), and am going to strive to bring it back into common usage. This will probably cause nothing save quizzical looks
On the other hand, I use ephemera as a singular noun. This more than occasionally causes quizzical looks

A word that has become obsolete is an obsoletism:

The earliest known use of the noun obsoletism is in the late 1700s.
OED's earliest evidence for obsoletism is from 1799, in the writing of G. E. Griffiths. oed.com

Obsoletism appears to be especially for [a group of] words, more than for items in general, as shown in Collins:

a thing, esp a word or group of words, that has gone out of use or is out of date

